# How was g and v_0 solved in the equation for motion?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

I am a game dev that recently became interested in implementing a character jump with a given height (H) and duration (T). I came across [this article](https://silverweed.github.io/Implementing_a_jump_with_a_given_duration_and_height/). In it, the author offers two solutions, but the one I am interested in is the first. Given the equation:

$$y (t) = p_0 +  v_0 t + 1/2 g t^2$$

Where, $p_0$ is the initial position of an object, $v_0$ is its initial velocity, $g$ is a gravitational constant, and $t$ is the duration of the object's movement. According to the article, to get a parabolic "jump effect" based on a given height and duration:

> We compute the equation for $t = T/2$ and for $t = T$, imposing that $y$ is $H$ in the first case and 0 in the second case. We also impose that $y0$ is 0 since we’re starting the jump from ground level (we may actually be starting from any height, but all we want from our jump is that it requires time T to be back to the starting height, so we can just set our reference frame so that the starting height is 0).

In that case,

$$p_0 = 0$$
$$H := y (T/2) = v_o (T/2) + 1/2 g (T/2)^2$$
$$0 := y (T) = v_0 (T) + 1/2 g (T)^2$$

Which I understand can be used to solve for $g$ and $v_0$, and in doing so, it gives:

$$g = -8 H / T^2$$
$$v_0 = -g T / 2$$

I'll admit that I am still working on upping my math skills, so I was wondering if anyone could walk me through how one could get to the answer that this author did when solving for $g$ and $v_0$?

(From what I could gather, to solve for $v_0$, you would subtract $1/2gt^2$ on both sides, then divide by $t$ when `H = 0`. However I am kind of confused by finding $g$. When $v_0 = 0$ in the first equation, you would just need to divide $t^2 / 8$ on both sides, but how and why does $V_0$ become zero?)

Comment: "... when `H=0`." But it's patently *not* zero, because you want the character to jump up some positive height. Anyway, you can solve for either $v_0$ or $g$ by elimination. Combine the equations in appropriate parts to eliminate one variable at a time. For example, if $a+2b=1$ and $a-b=0$, then $(a+2b)+2(a-b)=1+2\cdot0\implies3a=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I knew my assumption about `H=0` was incorrect. I will look into solving equations by elimination.